# OData annotation to display text and Id in a smart field

Tags: annotations, sapui5, cds

I'm having an application developed with CDS based annotations. I'm having a smart form with smart fields for Insert and Update functionalities.

Some of the smart fields are with the controlType="dropDownList". It displays the Id of the value list table and for the description also shows the Id, even though I've set the displayBehaviour="descriptionAndId".

How can I show the Id and Description in the Smart field drop downs using CDS based annotations?

Comment: Could you display the data returned by the server / SAP Gateway to the app (use Chrome developer tools) - this would enable me/us to see what values Description and Id are coming through with.

Comment: give the code of your CDS